# c# runtime skips an override, sometimes

Tags: c#, runtime, overriding

I am getting an obscure runtime crash bug in my c# code. It would appear from the stack trace that an override is sometimes, rarely, getting skipped, and the base class method is getting called instead. Pseudo code looks like this:

```
public class Widget : Gear
{
    public override string Spin()
    {
        return "crunch";
    } 
}

public class Gear
{
    public virtual string Spin()
    {
        return "whirr";
    }
}
```

and if I call this a thousand times, like so:

```
var widget = new Widget();
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(widget.Spin());
}
```

I might get one iteration calling the base class instead:

```
> ...
> crunch
> crunch
> crunch
> whirr
> crunch
> ...
```

Now my actual scenario is using Entity Framework and the error is happening at the EntityContext.SaveChanges() method, because something in my override didn't happen, and the stack trace shows the override was skipped, but the code above is representative of the symptoms.

My questions are: (1) is this possible? (2) is it preventable?

Comment: Could it be, rather than the base class is getting called, you're in fact getting an instance of the base class (instead of derived class) occasionally? Are you using a DI / IOC framework?

Comment: Could it be, also, that the stack trace doesn't log every call and it just not logging the parent class method?

Answer (score 5):

Your Gear class needs to mark the Spin function as virtual:

```
class Gear {
  public virtual string Spin() {
    return "whirr";
  }
}
```

In my test, I got a 1,000 "crunches".

If this is happening in your `EntityContext.SaveChanges()` method, then the posted code is, unfortunately, not representative of the problem.

Comment: agreed, that may be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The method Spin on class gear needs to be marked virtual, actually I'm suprised this compiles

my tests (with it set to virtual) work fine

Comment: it should compile with it not being virtual.  What that would mean is the parent method is non-virtual, then the child class shadows it with a virtual method (meaning if anyone inherited the child class any variables typed as the child or grandchild would use virtual dispatch, but if those instances were in a variable of type `Gear` they would use the `gear` method.